# Односоставное или двусоставное предложение?

Tags: предложение

Уважаемые коллеги!
Наверное мой вопрос покажется глупым,но один из моих коллег ввел меня в ступор,сказав,что предложение"Солнце,ветер."-это двусоставное предложение,еще и осложненное,а я знаю,что это односоставное номенативное(назывное),ну пусть осложненное однородными подлежащими.Является ли это предложение двусоставням????
Помогите в споре!

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!
Но мой коллега не считает его двусоставным неполным,наоборот я утверждала,что такая синтаксич.конструкция может быть двусоставным предложением,в случае,если оно неполное,т.е.из предыдущего контекста можно восстановить сказуемое.Но спор состоял в том,что предложение именно в таком виде,самостоятельное,без контекста является, по мнению,коллеги двусоставным и еще и осложненным...А осложнено оно отсутствием сказуемого....

Comment: Я такого определения такого вида осложнений не встречала.Далее,я утверждаю,что предложение является односоставным,номенативным(так как грам.основой этого предложения являются подлежащие,выраженные именем существительным в Им.п.).
Основная тема спора односоставное или двусоставное перед нами предложение?!
Спасибо вам!

Comment: Я такого определения вида осложнений не встречала.Далее,я утверждаю,что предложение является простым односоставным,номенативным(так как грам.основой этого предложения являются подлежащие,выраженные именем существительным в Им.п.).Простое он потому,что в нем два однородных подлежащих.

Основная тема спора односоставное или двусоставное перед нами предложение?!
Спасибо вам!

Answer (score 3):

Ваш коллега считает его двусоставным неполным (сказуемое "есть"опущено) с однородными подлежащими. Такая точка зрения существует, в качестве доказательства приводится другое время (было солнце, будет солнце). Более распространенной точкой зрения (она нашла отражение и в школьной грамматике) является признание таких предложений односоставными. А значит, это предложение сложное, обе части  односоставные назывные.